# Python 2.7 - I am Using smtplib to send mails to multiple people, but the subject line in email sent is not reflecting in every mail

Tags: python, smtplib

I am using smtplib to send mails to multiple users, I am reading email ids from `mail.txt` , and names of receivers from `names.txt` file and subject from `subject.txt` file,

Somehow the subject is not reflecting in all emails, only last mail that is sent has subject and others don't. But when I print the subject in each iteration it prints, I am  not sure why this is happening. I tried to change number of receipts and checked, but the issue doesn't solve. Also I tried to keep the import statements outside the loop as well.
Can you please help me with this code.

Code :

```
ob1 = open("names.txt","r")
fname = ob1.readlines()
ob1.close()
ob2 = open("mail.txt","r")
email = ob2.readlines()
ob2.close()
ob3 = open("subject.txt","r")
aname = ob3.readlines()
ob3.close()
for i in range(len(fname)): 
   import smtplib
   from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
   from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

   msg = MIMEMultipart()
   msg['From'] = 'my_email_id'
   msg['To'] = email[i]
   msg['Subject'] = aname[i]
   message = 'some mail text'
   msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

   mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
   mailserver.ehlo()
   mailserver.starttls()
   mailserver.ehlo()
   mailserver.login('my_email_id', '******')

   mailserver.sendmail('my_email_id',email[i],msg.as_string()) 

   mailserver.quit()
```

Comment: There are a few things wrong with your code. First of all, all your ob1..ob3.open() / .close() shoulb probably be replaced by `with open("...txt", "r") as ob1:`. You should really not import things inside your loop also. Could you also provide a sample of your txt files ? Thanks !

Comment: Also the mailserver ehlo, login and quit should certainly be outside the loop.